# Dissalow null values on creation only, but allow when modifying the table?

Tags: sql, postgresql, constraints

I'm wondering how I would go about doing the following. I have a table e.g.

```
CREATE TABLE person (
  name varchar(128),
  phone varchar(64)
);
```

Now I want to enforce NOT NULL on the phone when creating a new row, but I want to be able to later modify the row and remove the phone number. In my full example this is actually a foreign key reference, and the row the foreign key references may have to be deleted in the future for legal reasons. But when entered initially I need to enforce it being there.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Sharing your research helps everyone. Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! See also: [ask]

Comment: This sounds like logic that is better suited for your business layer, rather than your database. If you only expose Add methods that require the field, then you guarantee that it is populated when a record is entered. If you are looking for something that will prevent anyone adding invalid data, whatever solution you come up with won't work, because someone intent on doing it will do so (they will just add a record with a value, then immediately update it to null or -1 as in Gordon's answer).

Answer (score 3):

You would only be able to do this -- as you describe -- using triggers.

I would instead suggest that the column be `NOT NULL` and that you have a "not available" value, other than `NULL`.  If you were storing a string, then the empty string might suffice.  Or something like `'REMOVED FOR PRIVACY COMPLIANCE'`.

For a foreign key reference, simply have a value that means "not available" in the reference table.  I often give such values a key of `-1`.  This also has the advantage that inner joins work without dropping rows.

In databases that I work with, reference tables usually have such a value specifically so inner join's work.  We find that this reduces errors for analysts and others who use the databases.